# How to turn off the constant folding optimization in llvm

Tags: llvm, llvm-clang, llvm-ir

I am new to clang and llvm. I'm trying to generate an unoptimized version of bit code from a c source code. I found that the generated bit code is having the constant folding optimization which I don't want. 
I'm using this command: clang -O0 -Xclang -disable-O0-optnone test1.c -S -emit-llvm -o test1.ll

The test1.c file has the following code:

```
int test() {
int y;
y = 2 * 4;
return y;
}
```

The content of the test1.ll file:
[image]

Instead of generating an instruction for multiplying 2 and 4, it is directly storing the value 8 by doing the constant folding operation:
store i32 8, i32* %1, align 4

It would be really nice if someone kindly let me know what I am missing and how should I turn off the constant folding optimization. The version of llvm I am using is 6.0.0.

Thank you.

Comment: Do not post screenshots of code, paste the code instead.

Answer (score 1):

> It would be really nice if someone kindly let me know what I am missing and how should I turn off the constant folding optimization. The version of llvm I am using is 6.0.0.

It is a Clang feature and can't be turned off even with `-O0`. To workaround this try making variables global, pass them as parameters to the function, or just write the IR manually.